# R date from Excel not converting

Tags: r, excel, date

The following code I looked up on stackoverflow, nothing works to convert correctly from Excel to Date(). dput() shows the input dates from Excel. How to convert such numerics?

```
    data.3$Date <- as.Date(as.numeric(data.3$Date), origin="1899-12-30")
    z <- as.yearmon("39225",format="%Y%m")

    dput(data.3$Date)
    structure(c(-25545, -25551, -25529, -25521, -25545, -25522, -25544, 
-25538, -25547, -25548, -25546, -25521, -25526, -25521, -25537,
```

Comment: In R when I read.xlsx() I included the as.data.frame=TRUE. The field in question is a Date field but in the data.frame it is manifested as a Factor:: str(data.5)
'data.frame': 1555 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Date                      : Factor w/ 139 levels "12 May, 2007"

Comment: from the str() data.frame, one can wee that the $Date: Factor w/139 levels has "12 May, 2007". So inside the data file I get numerics, like 41411, etc.

Comment: When you read in the dataframe, it is helpful to write `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`, and then the date (and all other fields) will appear as character strings. Then it is much easier to convert it to date using `as.Date` from the `lubridate` package

Comment: ok I will do that stringsAsFactors...

Comment: this is a read.xlsx IS stringsAsFactors = FALSE available on read.xlsx? Yes it is

Comment: problem: str(data.4$Date)
 Date[1:1385], format: "1937-04-29" "1937-04-30" "1937-05-01" "1937-05-02"

Comment: The dates inside Excel are years 2005 thru 2008, not 1937...

Comment: data.4 <- read.xlsx(file, 4, as.data.frame=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=F)
str(data.4$Date)
 Date[1:1385], format: "1937-04-29" "1937-04-30" "1937-05-01" "1937-05-02"

Comment: WHY is the read.xlsx from Excel turing 2007-05-01 to 1937-05-01 ???

Comment: Original Hospital Location Examination Date Request ID
Abbeville OBGYN 05/01/07 CKYQSOA9840
Abbeville OBGYN 05/02/07 NPKGHYS10332

Answer (score 0):

To answer the last 5 comments questions... I applied this code to the date field from Excel, using strptime(data, format=), e.g.,

```
abberville_df4  <- subset(data.4, ((
  (data.4$Original.Hospital.Location == 'Abbeville' 
   & strptime(data.4$Date, format="%Y-%m-%d") >= "2007/04/30" 
   & strptime(data.4$Date, format="%Y-%m-%d") <= "2007/08/01"))))
```

Comment: YES, it now works ok using strptime() for the format; however, on the conditional test of 2007/04/30, I found that the data had been reversed so I needed to reverse the format="%Y-%m-%d" from format="%d-%m-%Y"